# A form of indication from matchsticks

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, matches

Here is another puzzle involving matchsticks.

[image]

Move only three matchsticks to get **a form of indication**. You cannot break, stack, or remove the matchsticks. Also, an arrow is not what I am looking for :-).

Edit: You are looking for **a word which is a form of indication.**

---

I realized that this may be too broad so I have edited this puzzle.

Comment: 3 match sticks out of all three? Or 3 matchsticks from each of them?

Comment: The first option, obviously.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Isn't the hint conforming with all 5 answers anyway?

Comment: @IAmInPLS How to be less visual? :D

Comment: @Techidiot By being more... "literal"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you are looking for! Good one @IAmInPLS

sorry for poor image edit

> [image: only 3]

Comment: what?! I tried to form this word several times :D

Comment: @oleslaw before the edit, the riddle said "be less visual".. so i kind of tricked with length of a matchstick  :P

Comment: This is it! Good job. I need to do some rework on this puzzle though, I think it could have been a good one except it was too broad.

Answer (score 3):

> [image]

How I think this fits the answer:

> Moving the bottom matchstick in each square, changes the squares to a square wave signal. A signal is a form of indication and so I have shown a form of indication. (This is validated by the fact that the squares are almost a matchstick length apart from each other.)

PS: Apologies for the shoddy image work, this computer has very limited capabilities.

Comment: No cookie for you, but nice lateral thinking!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

> [image]

... you're It.

Comment: What am I supposed to see?

Comment: Three letters forming a word.  The tag-line beneath the image (or this comment) should give it away. :)

Comment: What letters? Not clear.

Comment: the word is *tag*?

Answer (score 1):

You can

> move the matches to change nothing

And the result is

> "OOO" (out of order) which is an **indicator** that the device with the "OOO" sign is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This would involve balancing one match on it's end but...

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is "less visual", but

> [image]
>  **indic** is an abbreviated **form of "indication"**.
>  At least a [dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indic) told me so.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

> You pick three random matchsticks and move them to the place of the others so the image remains the same

because

> The three squares represent an horizontal semaphore :D 
>  [image]

Comment: Aaaaaand... No!

Comment: ^^' [tag:lateral-thinking] takes the worst of me

Answer (score 0):

Is it -> (Sorry for bad art)

> [image: 0/1=0] i.e. $0/1 = 0$

Hence

> It is a form of indicating an equation or mathematics.

Comment: why is that **a form of indication**?

Comment: May be it indicates an equation or math :D Not sure. Just gave a try

Comment: hahaha ok, sure why not?XD